# Etale coverings of non-projective curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves

For a smooth projective curve $Y$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic 0, it is known that there exists a one-to-one correspondence between finite \'{e}tale morphisms $f:X\to Y$ of degree $p$ (a prime), and $p$-torsion elements of $\mathrm{Pic}Y$.

Is this correspondence still true when one replaces $Y$ into a smooth quasi-projective curve?

Comment: No, because of nonconstant units in $\Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$. For example, for $Y=\mathbf{G}_m$, you have ${\rm Pic}\, Y = 0$ while $p:\mathbf{G}_m\to \mathbf{G}_m$ is an \'etale $\mu_p$-cover. In general you have the Kummer sequence $$0\to \mu_p\to \mathcal{O}^*_Y\to\mathcal{O}^*_Y\to 0$$ showing that ${\rm Hom}(\pi_1, \mu_p)$ is an extension of the $p$-torsion in ${\rm Pic}$ by $\Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}^*_Y)/\Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}^{*p}_Y)$.

Comment: Also I'm confused because you seem to claim that a subgroup of $\pi_1(Y)$ of index $p$ is always normal. Why is that true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you say is not correct: when $Y$ is projective, $p$-torsion elements of $\mathrm{Pic}(Y)$ correspond to *cyclic*  étale covers of degree $p$.  In general, the exact sequence (for the étale topology)
$$1\rightarrow \mu _p\rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m\xrightarrow{\ \times p\ }\mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow 1$$
gives an exact sequence 
$$1\rightarrow  A_Y^*/(A_Y^*)^p \rightarrow H^1(Y,\mu _p)\rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(Y)[p]\rightarrow 0$$where $A_Y$ is the ring of regular functions on $Y$.
So an étale $\mathbb{Z}/p$-cover  $f:X\rightarrow Y$ determines a $p$-torsion element of $\mathrm{Pic}(Y)$, but this element may be trivial without $f$ being trivial -- it means that $f$ is obtained by taking the $p$-th root of an invertible function.